# Warning: oci_connect(): ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied in /applicationname/module/UC/src/UC/Service/Base/Oracle.php on line 15

Tags: php, oracle, zend-framework, doctrine-orm

Im getting the below error when the application was trying to connect to Oracle. Application a PHP 7.4.6 RedHat8

Error:  Warning: oci_connect(): ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied in /uc01/apps/parking_portal/module/UC/src/UC/Service/Base/Oracle.php on line 15

I tried with the below peace of code to confirm the username and password is correct and to see if any deny. But it gave positive output and also im able to connect with those details in SQL Developer.

DB Connection Test:

```
<?php
// Create connection to Oracle
$conn = oci_connect("USER", "password", "//Host/Service");
if (!$conn) {
   $m = oci_error();
   echo $m['message'], "\n";
   exit;
}
else {  
   print "Connected to Oracle!";
}
// Close the Oracle connection
oci_close($conn);
?>
```

Just checking if anything problem with my PHP application or not. I just moved it from PHP 7.3 to PHP 7.4. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

When the below code warehouse.php calls the oracle.php to connect through oci_connect() its throwing the mentioned exception in the code.

warehouse.php

```
class Warehouse extends Oracle
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->user = "User";
        $this->password = "password";
        $this->connection = "(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP) (HOST = hostname.com) (PORT = 1521) ) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME=servicename)))";
        
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

and the oracle.php

```
<?php
namespace UC\Service\Base;

class Oracle
{
    protected $db_oracle;
    protected $user;
    protected $password;
    protected $connection;
    
    public function __construct() {
        $this->db_oracle = oci_connect(
            $this->user,
            $this->password,
            $this->connection
        );
    
        if (!$this->db_oracle)
        {
            throw new \Exception("A connection to the Database could not be established.");
        }
    }
```

I was wondering whether oci_connect is giving problem or not ?

Comment: if your test code works, and the production code not, the conclusion must be you tested something different. I am pretty sure that the connection is in a config file somewhere ..... Did you also migrate that to 7.4?

Comment: Both test code and actual application are in same server. Just checking migrating config file means? I have it in the respective folder but does it requires any modification?

Comment: That, I can not know but I assume there is some change missing. Maybe on the application level?

Comment: I have edited the query with more details can you check that for me please!

Comment: I am not a php guy. Sorry for that. Just a poor old dba.

Comment: The error is pretty straight-forward: you're connecting to a database, but the username/password is different in production. Since both of those properties appear to be hard-coded in your Warehouse class in addition to your connect string, you probably can't just re-use exactly the same code between dev and production. Ideally all of those properties should be in a configuration file and not hard-coded so that you could update/promote your code changes independently.